# The product $fg$ also is Riemann Integrable

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

I would like to show that if $f$ and $g$ are Riemann Integrable over $[a,b]$, then $fg$ is Riemann Integrable over $[a,b]$. However, I would like to use Lebesgues Theorem. This problem is from Roydens text.

Does this proof suffice?
Let $f$ and $g$ be bounded functions that are Riemann Integrable over $[a,b]$. Let $\mathscr{D}_{f}$ and $\mathscr{D}_{g}$ denote the set of discontinuities of $f$ and $g$ on $[a,b]$, respectively. By Lebesgues Theorem, we have that $m\left(\mathscr{D}_{f}\right) = 0$ and $m\left(\mathscr{D}_{g}\right) = 0$. Therefore, in order to show that $fg$ is Riemann Integrable over $[a,b]$, we need to show, by Lebesgues Theorem, that $m\left(\mathscr{D}_{f}\cup\mathscr{D}_{g}\right) = 0$. However, this is immediate by countable subadditivity of Lebesgue Measure.

Comment: Yes, this is fine.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for the conformation!